# Jquery loop through custom tags

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm going to have a custom tag on my forum, something like

```
[FISH]data|data|data....[/FISH]
```

In Jquery, how do I loop through all instances of the [FISH] tag and get all the data between it so I can render?  It must:

- Match pairs only (IE, print an error or ignore [FISH] which has no corresponding [/FISH]
- Be case insensitive

Comment: Do you mean that your "tag" will **actually** look like: `[FISH]...[/FISH]`, or will it be an HTML tag: `<FISH>...</FISH>`? If it's the former, you're SOL w/r/t jQuery.

Comment: It's the square bracketed one, so it conforms with forum bb code.  If it's impossible then I suppose I can use triangle brackets but I'm pretty sure I can do that already anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse such tags with regular expressions. Try:

```
console.log($('body').text().match(/(\[FISH\][^\[]*\[\/FISH\])/g));
```

[Here is a live snippet](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%28%5C%5BFISH%5C%5D%5B%5E%5C%5B%5D%2a%5C%5B%5C/FISH%5C%5D%29&input=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipisicing%20elit,%20sed%20do%20eiusmod%0Atempor%20incididunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.%20Ut%20enim%20ad%20minim%20veniam,%0Aquis%20nostrud%20exercitation%20ullamco%20laboris%20nisi%20ut%20aliquip%20ex%20ea%20commodo%0Aconsequat.%20%3Cp%3EDuis%20aute%20irure%20dolor%20in%20reprehenderit%20in%20voluptate%20velit%20esse%0Acillum%20dolore%20eu%20fugiat%20nulla%20pariatur.%20Excepteur%20sint%20occaecat%20cupidatat%20non%0Aproident,%20sunt%20in%20culpa%20qui%20officia%20deserunt%20mollit%20anim%20id%20est%20laborum.%3C/p%3E%0A%0A%3Ch2%3ELorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%3C/h2%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3ELorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipisicing%20elit,%20sed%20do%20eiusmod%0Atempor%20incididunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.%20Ut%20enim%20ad%20minim%20veniam,%0Aquis%20nostrud%20exercitation%20ullamco%20laboris%20nisi%20ut%20aliquip%20ex%20ea%20commodo%0Aconsequat.%20%5BFISH%5DDuis%20aute%20irure%20dolor%5B/FISH%5D%20in%20reprehenderit%20in%20voluptate%20velit%20esse%0Acillum%20dolore%20eu%20fugiat%20nulla%20pariatur.%20%5BFISH%5DExcepteur%20sint%20occaecat%20cupidatat%20non%0Aproident,%20sunt%20in%20culpa%20qui%20officia%20deserunt%20mollit%20anim%20id%20est%20laborum.%5B/FISH%5D%3C/p%3E%0A)

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter mentioned it is not possible using the square brackets but using <> brackets it is as simple as:

```
$("FISH")
```

Comment: Thanks, a quick question, is that case insensitive?